# Calculate Words Per Minute in real time

Tags: java, real-time, formula, words

Alright so I've tried to research some formulas on how to calculate words per minute, I couldn't find anything. I'm trying to use the current formula to calculate the words per minute (It is currently inside a thread):

```
errors = numberOfIncorrectCharacters();
int wordsCount = (int)(typingArea.getText().length()/5);  
int newWPM = (int)(wordsCount/seconds)-(errors*2);  
if(newWPM >= 0){
    WPM = newWPM;  
}
```

(seconds: I have a timer that executes every 1000 MS and than increments seconds by 1 everytime it does.)

And then I'm painting the variable WPM to the screen. But it's definitely not working correctly. If anyone can help me with a formula to calculate the words per minute in realtime, it would be very appreciated. Thanks for any help you offer.

Comment: *But it's definitely not working correctly* - what is the problem?

Comment: 1) Please use a consistent and logical indent for code blocks.  2) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: What's the *question?* Words per minute is just the number of words divided by the number of minutes. Your question is what?

Comment: @EJP: It can be defined as average words per min, or in his case, he wants it to be expected words per min based on the typing speed in the last second.

Comment: I know, but what if it doesn't take a minute? I tried using a formula and it's not working

Comment: *"not working"*  What output (values) were you expecting?  What did you get instead?  ..What about that SSCCE?

Comment: Sorry, I was expecting a "normal" (non-obscure) words per minute, but I am getting 0 WPM. And sorry I am kind of new to this.

Comment: Cool.  That answers the first 2 questions I asked.  What about an answer to the 3rd?  Also, to 'notify' someone of a new comment, you need to add @Andrew or similar.

Comment: Cant be of any further help without an SSCCE

Comment: @nhahtdh It *is* words divided by minutes. Which minutes, or seconds, he wants to measure over are up to him. There is still no question here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code looks like words per second. So you need minute.

```
float minute = (float)seconds/60;
```

Comment: Oh, I was researching it on a few sites and it said that the white spaces count.

Comment: I tried implementing that instead:
int newWPM = (int)(wordsCount/(seconds/60))-(errors*2);
but it still doesn't work

Comment: When measuring typing speed, a "word" is used to indicate 5 keystrokes, including punctuation.

Comment: Ok so basically I'm trying to make a program that calculates the WPM and it looks like this (for those who wanted a screenshot): http://gyazo.com/bd2d7b81b634b61573b9997860c39255

You type whatever is inside the textbox at the top inside the textbox at the button, and I want the WPM variable to tell you how many words per minute you type at, like the online typing tests. But I keep getting 0 for the formula that I'm using which is: int newWPM = (int)(wordsCount/(seconds/60))-(errors*2);

Comment: @JoshM it would be helpful if you add this in your question. Have you tried to repaint the panel. I assume you are using a panel and the count is a label. For better results put an SSCCE

Comment: Yeah I am constantly repainting the panel. Everything is working fine, except for the WPM, once I figure out the WPM "error" I am basically done this program. And SSCCE?

Comment: @JoshM Short, Self Contained, Correct (Compilable), Example. Refer to the [link](sscce.org)

Comment: I'm trying to use this formula now:
int wordsCount = (int)(typingArea.getText().length());
        int newWPM = (int)wordsCount/seconds*60;
and it seems like it increments too fast